# Hibernate One-to-One DTO-Entity population

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dto, one-to-one

I have 2 entities in my DB with one-to-one one directional mapping:
User and PasswordResetToken. The idea behind this is to create new token each time user requests password reset and store only the latest one.

Below are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Getter @Setter
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "usersSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "usersSeq", sequenceName = "SEQ_USERS", allocationSize = 1)
private long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name = "ROLE")
private Integer role;

}
///...
@Entity
@Table(name = "PASSWORD_RESET_TOKENS")
@Getter
@Setter
public class PasswordResetToken implements Serializable {

    private static final int EXPIRATION = 24;

    @Column(name = "TOKEN")
    private String token;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "EXPIRY_DATE")
    private Instant expiryDate;

    public PasswordResetToken() {
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(ZonedDateTime expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate.plus(EXPIRATION, ChronoUnit.HOURS).toInstant();
    }
}
```

Also, I have DTOs created for both of them to pass them around my app.
Code snippets:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class PasswordResetTokenModel {

    private String token;
    private ZonedDateTime expiryDate;
    private UserModel user;

}
```

UserModel is also used for Spring Security

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserModel extends User {

    public UserModel(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.getUsername();
    }
}
```

For population I've created 2 populators:

```
@Component
public class UserPopulatorImpl implements UserPopulator {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public UserModel populateToDTO(User user) {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), userDetailsService.getAuthorities(user.getRole()));
        userModel.setId(user.getId());
        return userModel;
    }

    @Override
    public User populateToDAO(UserModel userModel) {
        User user = new User();

        user.setEmail(userModel.getEmail());
        user.setName(userModel.getName());
        user.setPassword(userModel.getPassword());
        //TODO: change it!
         user.setRole(1);

        return user;
    }

}
//...
@Component
public class PasswordResetTokenPopulatorImpl implements PasswordResetTokenPopulator {

    @Autowired
    UserPopulator userPopulator;

    @Override
    public PasswordResetTokenModel populateToDTO(PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken) {
        PasswordResetTokenModel passwordResetTokenModel = new PasswordResetTokenModel();

        passwordResetTokenModel.setUser(userPopulator.populateToDTO(passwordResetToken.getUser()));
        passwordResetTokenModel.setToken(passwordResetToken.getToken());
        passwordResetTokenModel.setExpiryDate(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(passwordResetToken.getExpiryDate(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));

        return passwordResetTokenModel;
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordResetToken populateToDAO(PasswordResetTokenModel passwordResetTokenModel) {
        PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken = new PasswordResetToken();

        passwordResetToken.setExpiryDate(passwordResetTokenModel.getExpiryDate());
        passwordResetToken.setUser(userPopulator.populateToDAO(passwordResetTokenModel.getUser()));
        passwordResetToken.setToken(passwordResetTokenModel.getToken());

        return passwordResetToken;
    }
}
```

I'm saving object using

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(token);
```

When I use this code, I'm getting following exception

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.demo.megaevents.entities.User
```

There are currently 2 issues in this code:

1. Seems like Cascade.ALL in my OneToOne mapping is not working. If
   I create separate primary key in Token class everything works almost
   as expected but storing every created token in DB (more like
   OneToMany relation), however I want to avoid it as I need to store
   only one token per user in my DB
2. I don't like using new in populators, as it forces hibernate to create new object while flushing session. However, I also don't want to do another select to fetch this data from DB because just before mentioned populator I already do this query to fetch it and I think that it's an overhead.

Also, I really want to have DTOs and I don't want to remove DTO layer.

So, my questions:

1. What is the correct way to handle population between DTO and entities?
2. Are there any other improvements (probably architectural) to my solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably I am not understanding your application correctly, but maybe you would achieve the desired result if you add separate primary key in Token class, delete `@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")` and add in your User class the `@OneToOne (mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) PasswordResetToken token;`

Comment: @lenach87, I don't want user to be aware of a token, but other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would let `UserModel` extend `User`, but I guess you did that because you didn't want to have to copy all properties from `User` into `UserModel`. Too bad, because that's what is going to be needed to have a clean separation between the entity model and data transfer model.

You get that exception because you try to persist a `PasswordResetToken` that has a reference to a `User` object with an id, but the `User` isn't associated with the current session. You don't have to query the user, but at least association it with the session like this:

```
PasswordResetToken token = // wherever you get that from
Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
token.setUser(s.load(User.class, token.getUser().getId());
s.persist(token);
```

Cascading would cause the `User` to be *created*/*inserted* or *updated* via a SQL INSERT or UPDATE statement which is apparently not what you want.

You could do the `Session.load()` call in you populators if you want, but I'd not do that. Actually I would recommend not having populators at all, but instead create the entity objects in your service instead.

Normally you only have a few(mostly 1) ways of actually *creating* a new entity object, so the full extent of the transformation from DTO to entity will only be relevant in very few cases.

Most of the time you are going to do an update and for that, you should first select the existing entity and apply the **fields that are allowed to be changed** from the DTO on the entity object.

For providing the presentation layer with DTOs I would recommend using [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://blazebit.com/blog/2016/getting-started-with-blaze-persistence-entity-views.html) to avoid the manual mapping boilerplate and also improve performance of select queries.